# jQuery Fullcalendar event date defaulting to 20 August 2018 after March

Tags: json, symfony, fullcalendar

This is a strange issue I have not yet encountered - I have created a booking calendar within a SYmfony CRM using FullCalendar for a client but any events booked from the 31st March onwards this year default to 20th August when going to edit.

The calendar uses the JSON method to retrieve the data, and as far as I can tell the code is fine. Strangely enough, the correct date is shown in the calendar itself, it's just when you click through to edit it.

Here's an example of the JSON that shows the correct date when editing:

```
{"id":53,"desc":"SL SUE BECKMAN PRIVATE CAMP - 8:00am - 3:00pm Telephone:SL SUE BECKMAN ","bookingDate":{"date":"2018-03-25 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"endDate":{"date":"2018-03-25 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"startTime":{"date":"1970-01-01 08:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"endTime":{"date":"1970-01-01 15:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"course":1}
```

and here is an example of one that defaults to 20th August:

```
{"id":77,"desc":"WESTON HARRIERS PC PRIVATE BOOKING - 8:00am - 6:00pm Telephone:WESTON HARRIERS","bookingDate":{"date":"2018-04-08 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"endDate":{"date":"2018-04-08 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"startTime":{"date":"1970-01-01 08:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"endTime":{"date":"1970-01-01 18:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"course":1}
```

Here is a snippet from the Form Type that shows the dates for editing bookings in the CRM:

```
$builder->add('booking_date', DateTimeType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'Start Date',
        'required' => true,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label required'
        ),
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control pickr required'
        )
    ));
$builder->add('end_date', DateTimeType::class,
    array(
        'label' => 'End Date',
        'required' => true,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label required'
        ),
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control pickr required'
        )
    ));
```

Like I say, it displays fine in the calendar with the correct date, the database stores the correct date and the JSON also seems to hold the correct date - but from the end of March onwards, it defaults to 20th August. It just seems like a really random thing but I'm hoping someone may have encountered it or something similar before?

**EDIT:**

Here's the same booking as it looks in the calendar config under events:

```
{ id: 'b_77', resourceId: '1', start: '2018-04-08 08:00:00', end: '2018-04-08 18:00:00', color: '#3eb67e', desc: 'WESTON HARRIERS PC PRIVATE BOOKING - 8:00am - 6:00pm Telephone:WESTON HARRIERS', url: '/calendar/edit-booking/77' }
```

It has the correct start and end dates.

Comment: "defaults to 20th August". Strange  because the only dates in that JSON are 8th April 2018 or 1st Jan 1970. It's hard to see how either of those could ever be mis-interpreted. Also those don't look like fullCalendar event objects. What exactly is it which is "defaulting" anyway? A control on your page? A value stored in the DB? The details of this are not very clear, nor is it obvious how this is relevant to fullCalendar, which doesn't have any editing forms built in.

Comment: It's a Symfony CRM that implements FullCalendar. The 'edit' page pulls out the data stored in the database and converts the date into a DateTime text widget. The JSON above is just data from the database. It gets adapted into the correct format for FC. I will add the config to the question.

Comment: If it's the edit page which is at fault, and the edit page pulls its data from the database, then I can't see what that has to do with your fullCalendar config, especially if fullCalendar is displaying the information correctly.

Comment: It's just a way to show that the dates being pulled out are correct - I cannot see where the issue lies, that's the problem

Comment: The finished, rendered HTML of the edit page would be a good place to start. Then trace back through the code as to how it generates that.

Comment: Right - it turns out it was the flatpickr that I was assigning to the date drop down. If I use the standard Doctrine text widget, the correct date is pulled through so I'll just use that.